Higher massive integer spin field (or spin-3 field)
I've been revisiting chapter 8 of Schwartz's Quantum Field Theory book. Toward the end, he describes a method for constructing the Lagrangian of massive integer spin particles by separating the transverse and longitudinal parts and eliminating dangerous ghosts. This method is applied to spin-1 and spin-2 fields, resulting in the Lagrangian for rank-1 and rank-2 symmetric tensors, respectively.
Building on this, I attempted to construct the Lagrangian for a massive spin-3 particle, as outlined in problem 8.8, but I ran into issues with ghost removal. The ghosts don’t seem to disappear as expected using this approach. After doing some research, I found that the more standard method for constructing the Lagrangian for a massive spin-s particle involves introducing auxiliary fields of rank $s-2$, $s-1$, ... , down to 0, to work with the rank-$s$ symmetric traceless tensor. For spin-2, for example, combining the spin-0 auxiliary field $h^\mu_\mu$ gives the well-known Fierz-Pauli Lagrangian.
However, I haven't been able to find a way to construct the Lagrangian by following Schwartz's approach, which removes ghosts directly from the symmetric rank-$s$ tensor. Can anyone explain if it's possible to construct the Lagrangian using Schwartz’s method, and if so, what the resulting Lagrangian looks like?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/713534/2451

The discussion by Schwartz is limited to the cases he considered. In order to construct actions for massive higher spin fields you need auxiliary fields. The problem has been solved https://inspirehep.net/literature/91804 by Singh and Hagen. The idea itself goes back to Fierz and Pauli who tested it for the spin-two case. However, there is a coincidence for the spin-two case that the single auxiliary field (scalar) can be combined with the traceless rank-two tensor into a traceful field, which can make one think that there is no auxiliary field. It is impossible to write down a consistent Lorentz-invariant local action for the massive spin-three with just $Z_{\mu\nu\lambda}$ as Schwarzt seems to imply.
